# Does SAP Vora 2.1 need a Hadoop / Spark cluster? And can PySpark be used?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, vora

As per the documentation *SAP_Vora_Installation_Admin_Guide_2.0_en.pdf*, it is required to have an Hadoop / Spark cluster running and a Kubernetes cluster running as well.

Now my question is, why do you need this Hadoop / Spark cluster? Because SAP Vora can read from HDFS, WebHDFS and so on.

So is this just that if you have a Spark job you can just run it on Spark cluster and if it needs data from HANA / Vora it can access it? Or does Vora also use the Spark cluster to process data on?

Because right now it looks like Spark can use Vora but not that Vora can use Spark (the Vora UI tools like the SQL Editor and so on). Because the Zeppelin that you can attach to Vora is just used for visualization (as I understand it, correct me if I am wrong please).

My second question is if it possible to use PySpark on the Hadoop / Spark cluster to interact with Vora and not just Scala Spark.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct: Spark can access Vora 2.1 but Vora 2.1 cannot interact with Spark and therefore does not require a Hadoop/Spark cluster to be available. However, if you do not have Hadoop then you must have an alternative data store to load data from e.g. S3, ADL.

Yes, it is possible to use PySpark to interact with Vora.

Comment: I do however have some follow up question. 1. if you look at the architecture picture you can see that HDFS is also linked to the VORA engines. How this work then? 2. Is there an example where they use pyspark with 2.1? because all the examples i can find are 1.3 or older, and would like to get an updated look on how this is done on the new architecture in 2.1.